# How to compare long/lat from input and show nearest long/lat from the list

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to make a function in excel where the user will input the coordinates, and the result will list all nearest building from the user input. Is it possible to do it this way?

| User input |  |
| --- | --- |
| Longitude | 14.123200 |
| Latitude | 123.10056 |

List to Result:

| Location Name | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Building 1 | 14.123213 | 123.10000 |
| Building 2 | 14.123313 | 123.10100 |

List to query:

| Location Name | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Building 1 | 14.123213 | 123.10000 |
| Building 2 | 14.123313 | 123.10100 |
| Building 3 | 14.123413 | 123.10200 |
| Building 4 | 14.123513 | 123.10300 |
| Building 5 | 14.123613 | 123.10400 |
| Building 6 | 14.123713 | 123.10500 |

Comment: What do you consider as "nearest"?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? The problem is that you essentially have a list of X and Y coordinates and are trying to say "if I have a random set of coordinates which of these is closest" and you can't consider just the X or just the Y coordinates separately. You will need to use trigonometry to calculate "distance to each point" and then pick the smallest. Your X and Y "start" (supplied coordinates) and "end" (building coordinates) gives you horizontal and vertical distance so you need to calculate the straight line for each set.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate distances between buildings in an auxiliary column and then sort and filter results. I hope you have a new version of Excel.
[image: Sort on distances]